# Revision Control For Windows CE

Tags: version-control, windows-ce

I have a HP Jornada 720 with Windows CE 3, called Handheld PC 2000. And as a good developer, I want to turn it into a fully-featured Scheme development environment. I already have [Pocket Scheme](http://www.mazama.net/scheme/pscheme.htm) on it, but now I need a revision control for my pocket development environment.

Then I want to know: Where I can get it?

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was inspired when I bought this device(also, I love old devices). **:-)**